# Does SQL treat multiple records as one when you wrap them in parenthesis in a VALUES clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was recently working on a stored procedure that would insert multiple records into a table variable and came across what seemed to be an oddity, but now I realize that I may have just been confusing myself by overlooking the obvious. Regardless, take the table variable definition as:

```
DECLARE @TableVariable TABLE(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1), SomeValue NVARCHAR(1000));
```

When I execute the following insert statement, it succeeds with no issues:

```
INSERT INTO @TableVariable (SomeValue) VALUES
    ('Value 1'), ('Value 2')
```

However, when I came back to clean up the query, I added parenthesis to the `VALUES` clause in an effort to show where it ended without adding a comment (don't know why, probably a habit from C# of wrapping in `#region` tags):

```
INSERT INTO @TableVariable (SomeValue) VALUES (
    ('Value 1'), ('Value 2')
);
```

This produced an error stating that there were fewer columns in the `INSERT` than there were in the `VALUES` clause:

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

My theory is that it sees the version with the parenthesis as an attempt to insert a single value, with multiple columns since I wrapped all of the entries in parenthesis.

---

My question is, why did that **officially** make a difference?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ecbd57767deb0d97341af41051213295)** - should help to visualize the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is simple.  `VALUES` is followed by a list of values for a row.  Each row is within its own set of parentheses.

So:

```
values (1), (2)
```

is two rows with one column.

```
values ( (1) ), ( (2) )
```

is two rows with one column -- in fact the same as above.

But:

```
values ( (1, 2) )
```

is either an error.  Or in databases that support tuples one row with one column that has a value of `(1, 2)`.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but I wanted to make 100% sure from someone with loads more experience in SQL. Thanks! I'll accept as soon as SO will let me.